# Laravel: How to filter objects by date, where date is a UNIX timestamp?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent

I'm starting with Laravel (`4.2`) and I would like to filter table's rows by column which is a UNIX timestamp. Specifically I need `timestamp` to be in some (date) range.

I imagine it would look something like:

```
$objs = DB::table('[table name]')->where('timestamp', [condition])->get();
```

I'm using `mongodb 2.2.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `whereBetween`.

```
$range = [timestamp1, timestamp2];
->whereBetween('timestamp', $range);
```

Also note that all methods on the query builder support Closure:

```
->whereBetween('timestamp', function($q){
    //some logic
    return [timestamp1, timestamp2];
});
```